# php-fpm installed and running, but Apache24 still using CGI

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php-cgi

On my Freebsd server, I have Apache installed with php-fpm, but phpinfo() reports that the server is using CGI/FastCGI instead of FPM/FastCGI.

I can see several children of php-fpm, but they have no activity:

```
73819  -  IW         0:00.00 php-fpm: pool www (php-fpm)
73820  -  IW         0:00.00 php-fpm: pool www (php-fpm)
73821  -  IW         0:00.00 php-fpm: pool www (php-fpm)
73822  -  IW         0:00.00 php-fpm: pool www (php-fpm)
73823  -  IW         0:00.00 php-fpm: pool www (php-fpm)
<many more>
```

The php-cgi process are all active:

```
86203  -  I          0:04.84 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
86204  -  I          0:00.20 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
86232  -  I          0:03.44 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
86233  -  I          0:04.85 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
86253  -  I          0:00.79 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
<many more>
```

I have a second identical server that is configured the same and works great. On the second server, phpinfo() reports that php-fpm = active. I've compared conf & ini files from both servers and can't seem to find it.

Any suggestions on where to look, or how to further debug?

Answer (score 0):

Disable mod_fcgid

Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi plus its specific configuration
Example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    # Unix sockets require 2.4.7 or later
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```